# pandas groupby condition and re-shape the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in which I am trying to count the total number of the values of "MISSING" per column grouped by A, B and C but I am trying to keep it in the format below , I am not sure if I have to reshape the dataframe or use stack:

```
               A   B           C        D        E        F  
0     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball       21  MISSING  MISSING            
1     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball       17  MISSING  MISSING            
2     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball  MISSING       12       23             
3  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball  MISSING        5  MISSING             
4  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball       10  MISSING  MISSING             
5  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball        5  MISSING  MISSING
```

This is what I would like the result to be:

```
A        B   Column Name   Missing Count
Miami   Heat FL  D             1
Miami   Heat FL  E             2
Miami   Heat FL  F             2
Orlando Magic FL D             1
Orlando Magic FL E             2
Orlando Magic FL F             3
```

This code does not work:

```
df = finalDF.assign(Missing Count = finalDF.eq("MISSING").sum(axis=1))
.groupby(['A','B','C']) ['Missing Count'].count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df = (df.assign(**df[['D', 'E', 'F']].isnull())
            .pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], values=['D', 'E', 'F'], aggfunc='sum')
            .reset_index()
            .melt(['A', 'B'], var_name='Column Name', value_name='Missing Count')
            .sort_values('A'))
print(new_df)
               A   B Column Name  Missing Count
0     Miami Heat  FL           D            1.0
2     Miami Heat  FL           E            2.0
4     Miami Heat  FL           F            2.0
1  Orlando Magic  FL           D            1.0
3  Orlando Magic  FL           E            2.0
5  Orlando Magic  FL           F            3.0
```

if they aren't `NaN`

```
df[['D', 'E', 'F']].eq('MISSING')
```

---

**First step** : [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with `**`:

```
print(df.assign(**df[['D', 'E', 'F']].isnull()))
               A   B           C      D      E      F
0     Miami_Heat  FL  Basketball  False   True   True
1     Miami_Heat  FL  Basketball  False   True   True
2     Miami_Heat  FL  Basketball   True  False  False
3  Orlando_Magic  FL  Basketball   True  False   True
4  Orlando_Magic  FL  Basketball  False   True   True
5  Orlando_Magic  FL  Basketball  False   True   True
```

This is a dynamic way to create a DataFrame with `True` or `False` in the columns where we want to count missing values. To understand `**` you can see : [What is the purpose and use of **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs) and [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

**Second step**

Now we can count, one of the simple ways is by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table), we could also have used `groupby`.

```
print(df.assign(**df[['D', 'E', 'F']].isnull())
        .pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], values=['D', 'E', 'F'],aggfunc='sum'))
                    D    E    F
A             B                
Miami_Heat    FL  1.0  2.0  2.0
Orlando_Magic FL  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

I recommend you see : [`How pivot a DataFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

**Finally**: [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) using [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
previously not to lose information about the `index`.

```
print(df.assign(**df[['D', 'E', 'F']].isnull())
      .pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], values=['D', 'E', 'F'], aggfunc = 'sum')
      .reset_index()
      .melt(['A', 'B'], var_name='Column Name', value_name='Missing Count'))
               A   B Column Name  Missing Count
0     Miami_Heat  FL           D            1.0
1  Orlando_Magic  FL           D            1.0
2     Miami_Heat  FL           E            2.0
3  Orlando_Magic  FL           E            2.0
4     Miami_Heat  FL           F            2.0
5  Orlando_Magic  FL           F            3.0
```

maybe here [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + `reset_index` could be also works well. But we need then `.rename_axis(columns = 'Column Name')` previously and `.rename('Missing Count')` before `reset_index`

---

[`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in order to get expected output sorted.

we could also have melted first and then count....

Comment: Thank you, this works...can you please walk me through the code so I can fully understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B'])
df.rename(columns={'variable':'Column Name'}, inplace=True)
df[df['value']=='MISSING'].groupby(['A','B', 'Column Name']).count().reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.